# Right way to remove an ionic cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

From the install steps we need two commands to install plugins

eg:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/secure-storage@4
```

to uninstall I use

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-secure-storage
```

but still, see that the plugin reference in the package.json file

my questions are:

1. why are two steps required for installing and what do they do [cordova plugin add vs npm install]
2. How to completely remove a plugin if I'm not using it from my workspace and project files.

Comment: why using 2 lines for install? `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage` is good

Comment: it's mentioned in the plugin documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/secure-storage/

Answer (score 4):

First, let's talk about some simple architecture before explaining the mentioned example to make things clearer.

Cordova plugins are collections of platform native code that can be invoked using JavaScript. In simple words, they're wrapping native code (e.g.Java for Android/Swift for IOS) with JavaScript so you can call this native code using JavaScript only.

Ionic Native plugins do the same, but instead of wrapping the native code, they wrap Cordova JavaScript plugins with TypeScript so you can use TypeScript decorators that add Promise, Observable, and Typing support to Cordova plugins that rarely support them by default.

Now that we know the above, let's explain the commands you mentioned in your example:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-storage
```

You run this command to install the Cordova JavaScript plugin. Then you run the second command which is:

```
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/secure-storage@4
```

You run this command to install the TypeScript wrapper that enables you to use the Cordova plugin you installed in the first command using TypeScript inside your Ionic project.

Subsequently, when you decide to remove a plugin from your Ionic project, you should do the same and remove both the Cordova plugin and the TypeScript wrapper of that plugin using the following commands:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-secure-storage
```

This command removes Cordova JavaScript plugin.

```
$ npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/secure-storage
```

This command removes TypeScript wrapper of that plugin.

If you're interested in further reading check the following url:

[Architectural overview of Cordova platform](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html)

[Ionic Native: Native Powers for Your App by Ionic CEO Max Lynch](https://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-native-native-powers-for-your-app/)